# attempting to count hours, returnssummarized dict() but no list

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a text file, scan each line for the time in hh:mm:ss format and then list, count and sort the hours in the hh location.

so far I have been able to isolate the hour part of each line, but have made some mistake with the dictionary so that it lists the entries cumulatively

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

handle = open(name)

d = dict()

for lin in handle :
    if lin.startswith('From ') : #isolates lines w/ emails
        lin = lin.split()
        lin = lin[5]
        lin = lin.split(':')
        hour = lin[0]
        d[hour] = d.get(hour,0) + 1

print(d)
```

the code returns the following:

```
{'09': 2, '18': 1, '16': 4, '15': 2, '14': 1, '11': 6, '10': 3, '07': 1, '06': 1, '04': 3, '19': 1, '17': 2}
```

I understand that I have created a dictionary for all of the time occurrences which is what I wanted, but I'm failing to see how to create a sorted list of the keys and values. What is the function I should be looking to use?

the desired output is a sorted list as follows, and is just a manipulation of the data I have already assembled adequately:

04 3

06 1

07 1

09 2

10 3

11 6

14 1

15 2

16 4

17 2

18 1

19 1

Comment: I shook out some cobwebs and de-indented the print function, and now it returns the correct summary line. I feel pretty dumb...

Comment: also share the file you intend to open in the question

Comment: @AniketNavlur how can I do that the most efficiently? the file itself is a bit long in text

Comment: @Jon just the output of `grep '^From ' mbox-short.txt | head` would probably be enough (i.e. the lines starting with "From ")

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding and am completing a coursera python course where the point is to build a sorted list - I don't think we have covered grep yet?

Comment: @Jon https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [(key,d[key]) for key in d]
l.sort(key= lambda x: int(x[0]))
for i in l:
    print(*i)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN1ew.png)

**Explanation:**
First I made a list of tuples containing key value pairs of the dict. Which will be like
`[(key,value), (key, value), ...]`
The I sorted the list based on the first element in each tuple, instead of lambda u can also use helper function which takes a tuple as argument and returns first parameter like this:

```
def helper(x):
    return int(x[0])
l.sort(key= helper)
```

After sorting, I printed every tuple in new line.( in the print instead of i, I have used *i, i.e I am [unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) it, so that we get all elements in the tuple printed seperately)

Comment: it definitely works! the only problem is I don't understand most of it :( could you please walk me through your code so I can understand? I'm quite new to python

Comment: I have added some explanation, hope it helps you understanding it. If u have problem understanding the flow of control in python programs try using python tutor: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: thank you, I will definitely check out pythontutor.com!

Answer (score 0):

The error was at the indentation block after the "for" loop for your "if" conditional:

```
for lin in handle :

    if lin.startswith('From ') : #isolates lines w/ emails
        lin = lin.split()
        lin = lin[5]
        lin = lin.split(':')
        hour = lin[0]
        d[hour] = d.get(hour,0) + 1
        print(d)
```

Alright, with that out of the way I think there are some logical snags with the code block and what I think you are trying to achieve. So let me see if I can be of some help here.

Generally while starting to code or doing an initial proof of concept, it is best you do not reuse a variable name and have a distinctive, readable variable name so it is easier to debug.

I think the best data structure for your use case would be a list instead of a dictionary, for what you are attempting to do: list, count and sort.

So if I were to write a code block for this approach it would be:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"

hour_list = list()

with open(name) as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        if line.startswith("From "):
            line_split = line.split()
            time = line_split[5]
            time_split = time.split(":")
            hour = time_split[0]
            hour_list.append(int(hour))

print(hour_list)
hour_list.sort() ## Sorting the elements in the hour list, it is inplace method
print(hour_list)
print(len(hour_list))
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Enter file:
[9, 18, 16, 15, 15, 14, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 19, 17, 17, 16, 16, 16]
[4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19]
27
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Oh, I see you have edited your question extensively just a few back. The answer provided by Abhishek, in that case, should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {'09': 2, '18': 1, '16': 4, '15': 2, '14': 1, '11': 6, '10': 3, '07': 1, '06': 1, '04': 3, '19': 1, '17': 2}
```

**Code:**

```
list = sorted([f'{key} {value}' for key, value in dict.items()])
print(*list, sep='\n')
```

**How it works:**

```
for key, value in dict.items()
```

For each 'key': 'value' pair of your dict, build a string of both:

```
f'{key} {value}'
```

...and pass it to a list - see the surrounding brackets [] - this one-line style is called a 'list comprehension', which is a coding concept for convenience. Then call the Python built-in method sorted() passing that list (which is an iterable object).

The print() method also accepts iterables, but to unpack them in place you need to put the * character, which is called the splat operator. Changing the separator for the unpacked elements to '\n' results in linebreaks between the elements.

You can also write this code in conventional style:

```
my_list = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    my_list.append(f'{key} {value}')
    # or even more conventional: my_list.append(str(key) + ' ' + str(value))
sorted(my_list)
```